# Using EXISTS return wrong values in Script via Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, exists

I have a problem with following queries.

**Part 1**

Updates the table.

**Part 2**

Changes the column-name.

If I rerun the script via Management Studio I get an error,

> The column "permissiontype_id" does not exist.

The Select Statement in Exists shows the right result...

I get such errors with some statements in my script and need to get rid of them...

**First Statement**

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE NAME = N'permissiontype_id'
        AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[dbo].[gptbl_user_permission]')
    )
BEGIN
UPDATE gptbl_user_permission
SET permissiontype_id = 1
WHERE objecttype_id = 'resultinfo'
END
GO
```

**Second Statement**

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE NAME = N'permissiontype_id'
        AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[dbo].[gptbl_user_permission]')
    )
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[gptbl_user_permission]

DROP CONSTRAINT PK_gptbl_user_permission

EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[gptbl_user_permission].[permissiontype_id]'
    , 'permissiontype'
    , 'COLUMN';

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[gptbl_user_permission] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_gptbl_user_permission PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [objecttype_id] ASC
    , [permissiontype] ASC
    , [user_id] ASC
    )
    WITH (
            PAD_INDEX = OFF
            , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
            , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
            , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
            , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
            )
END
GO
```

Comment: `If I rerun the script`: if you really mean `rerun` then it should fail, because the column was renamed to `permissiontype` instead of `permissiontype_id`.. Does the script run without errors the first time? Can you show us the DDL of `gptbl_user_permission`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is a compile time error and its not because of `EXISTS`. If you run your `EXISTS` query after the second run, it will not return anything

```
SELECT 1
FROM sys.columns
WHERE NAME = N'permissiontype_id'
    AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[dbo].[gptbl_user_permission]')
```

So at runtime, the control will never reach your `UPDATE` after the first run.

```
UPDATE gptbl_user_permission
SET permissiontype_id = 1
WHERE objecttype_id = 'resultinfo'
```

The reason you get this error is because after the initial run, SQL Server checks the syntax of the query, the table and columns involved in this query. At this point SQL Server knows there is no column `permissiontype_id` and raises an error.

**Solution**

Since this error is due to compilation, you can use dynamic sql to force compilation to occur at run time for `UPDATE` like this:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE NAME = N'permissiontype_id'
        AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[dbo].[gptbl_user_permission]')
    )
BEGIN
EXEC sp_executeSQL N'
UPDATE gptbl_user_permission
SET permissiontype_id = 1
WHERE objecttype_id = ''resultinfo'''
END
GO
```

Since `EXISTS` will return false every time after the first run, Hence the dynamic `UPDATE` statement will never get compiled and you won't get an error.

Comment: Great. executeSQL solved it in this point. Will rewrite some parts of my script with this now.

Thanks =)

Comment: @SteveFörster - I got the same issue few years back. `IF EXISTS` can only take you so far :)